# Angular component does not react on boolean property changes

Tags: angular, eventemitter, property-binding

I have subscription on event emitter in my component initialization

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.linksService.droppableZoneActivation.subscribe(
        (activate: boolean) => {
            this.activated = activate;
        }
    );

}
```

`this.linksService.droppableZoneActivation` - boolean event emitter. I receive emitted values, that change from false to true and vice versa. And here is component template that uses that value:

```
<div *ngIf="activated">

    <div dnd-droppable (onDropSuccess)="addEntity($event)">

        <a [routerLink]="['/features/links']" tabindex="-1">

            ...

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

Component reacts on `this.activated` changes only twice. Sometimes it does not react at all. What's the problem?
Values are emitted from service by calling methods from other components.

```
activateDroppableZone(): void {

    this.droppableZoneActivation.emit(true);

}


deactivateDroppableZone(): void {

    if (!this.selectedEntities.length) {
        this.droppableZoneActivation.emit(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: not enough to go on, post the code logic regarding on how droppableZoneActivation is called and what logic is emitting value to it

Comment: I have added some info to my question

Comment: post the logic/html of what is calling activateDroppableZone and deactivateDroppableZone.if the emit is only working twice or never, the problem must be there.

Comment: I have tested emitted values. Values were emitted regularly more than 10 times. But *ngIf did not react on expression changes. When I used [clas. ... ] with 'activated' expression that did not work too...